# How to understand the behaviour of 'right' and 'bottom' in CSS positioning?

Tags: css

Please check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/manuchadha/rc0dxog1/12/

How does `bottom` and `right` work in css as in the following example? They don't seem to have any effect.

HTML

```
<div id="div3"> top left bottom right div</div>
```

CSS - this CSS moves the div as per `top` and `left`. Right and bottom have no effect.

```
div#div3 {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#eaf;
  position:relative;  
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  right:50px;
  bottom:50px;

}
```

This CSS moves the div up as expected.

```
div#div3 {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#eaf;
  position:relative;  
  right:50px;
  bottom:50px;
}
```

But this CSS seems to give `top` and `left` priority over `bottom` and `right`.

```
div#div3 {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#eaf;
  position:relative;  
  right:50px;
  bottom:50px;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
}
```

What is the expected behavior if I give all four properties in the CSS - `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`? Shall I specify only one of `right` or `left` and one of `bottom` or `top`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `position:relative`, you cannot specify all four at once. In fact this only makes sense if you are using `position:absolute`.

`relative` means 'shift the element a certain amount vertically and horizontally *relative* to its normal position'. If you specify `left:10px` and `right:10px` at the same time, what does that mean? Should the browser move the element to the left or to the right? It is not clear. So, in practice, one rule is simply ignored.

Take a look at [MDN's article on CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> Except for the case just described (of absolutely positioned elements filling the available space):
>
> - If both top and bottom are specified (technically, not auto), top wins.
> - If both left and right are specified, left wins when direction is ltr (English, horizontal Japanese, etc.) and right wins when direction is rtl (Persian, Arabic, Hebrew, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You should save calling `top` `left` `right` and `bottom` for `position: absolute`

Try calling `margin-right` and `margin-bottom`